# Problema con google maps api JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Quiero crear un mapa en mi web que cuando apretes diferentes direcciones que estan al costado, se muestren en el mapa, sin salir de la pagina, se modificaria solo la ubicacion de la pagina, como la siguiente web:

https://www.swissmedical.com.ar/smgnewsite/prepaga/mapa_de_sucursales.php

Alguien me da una mano? Busque en toda la info de `API Google Maps` y no pude encontrar un ejemplo. Gracias!

Comment: Hola Lucas, ¿cuál es el problema que tienes o que tiene tu código?

Comment: Hola! El problema es que genero el mapa, con la ApiKey y todo, pero no encuentro las funciones para apretar en una direccion y que se me modifique el mismo mapa en el que estoy

Comment: Ayudaría que compartieras el código donde agregas el market point

Comment: Si es sólo un marcador, podrías cambiar la posición a tu marcador y centrar el mapa si lo puntos están en lugares muy distantes. 
Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por los [ejemplos de google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es)

Comment: Hay que decir bien el problema, es decir, necesitas que se te ubique a ti... tu ubicación?, Ahora si no quieres tu ubicación la forma mas facil es cargar iframe de tu mapas previamente guardados, eso es mas facil que utilizar la api de google maps

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es generar la lista donde tengas los atributos "latitud" y "longitud". El presente código funciona, para comprobarlo, agrega tu API KEY

```js
 $(".actualizarMapa").on("click", function() {
      initMap($(this).attr("latitud"), $(this).attr("longitud"));
     });
    

      function initMap(latitud, longitud) {       

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud),
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }

 function initMapByDefault() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -8.1167518, lng: -79.0371252};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
   </style>

 <body>
  <a id="ubicacionSucural1" style="cursor: pointer;" latitud="-8.1167518" longitud="-79.0371252" class="actualizarMapa">
        <p>Sucursal La tiendita de Don Pepe Trujillo </p>       
        <p>Calle Francisco Pizarro 551 </p>
    </a>
   <br>
    <a id="ubicacionSucural2" style="cursor: pointer;" latitud="-12.0553436" longitud="-77.063575" class="actualizarMapa">
        <p>Sucursal La tiendita de Don Pepe Lima </p>       
        <p>Calle Francisco Pizarro 551 </p>
    </a>
    <div id="map"></div>   
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AQUI_COLOCAS_TU_API_KEY&callback=initMapByDefault"
    async defer></script>

  </body>
```

Para la solución de esta pregunta me he basado en el ejemplo encontrado en la misma web oficial de Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

y hay otro ejemplo más como dice el buen `El Asiduo` en: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es

Comment: Deberías indicar el html mínimo y necesario para que funcione tu ejemplo.

Comment: listo mi estimado :D

Comment: Sos muy bueno. No se lo merecen. ;-)

Comment: gracias :D creo que esto es lectura recomendada: http://fredyfx.com/saludos-nueva-generacion-de-programadores

Answer (score 0):

Ese codigo funciona , pero lo llevo a mi html y no funciona! Que puedo hacer? Gracias!

```js
 $(".actualizarMapa").on("click", function() {
      initMap($(this).attr("latitud"), $(this).attr("longitud"));
     });
    

      function initMap(latitud, longitud) {       

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud),
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }

 function initMapByDefault() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -8.1167518, lng: -79.0371252};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
   </style>

 <body>
  <a id="ubicacionSucural1" style="cursor: pointer;" latitud="-8.1167518" longitud="-79.0371252" class="actualizarMapa">
        <p>Sucursal La tiendita de Don Pepe Trujillo </p>       
        <p>Calle Francisco Pizarro 551 </p>
    </a>
   <br>
    <a id="ubicacionSucural2" style="cursor: pointer;" latitud="-12.0553436" longitud="-77.063575" class="actualizarMapa">
        <p>Sucursal La tiendita de Don Pepe Lima </p>       
        <p>Calle Francisco Pizarro 551 </p>
    </a>
    <div id="map"></div>   
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZhH6WXRQpmvkrpZ6w-kBIQTqOwHuPncI&callback=initMapByDefault"
    async defer></script>

  </body>
```

Comment: esto no es una respuesta, masbien, agrega el comentario a la respuesta que te he dado, Tecla F12 en tu navegador y escribe el error que te sale. saludos